# cron job not working properly, but works on manually

Tags: php, cron

I have a file that works fine from manual execution, but it does not work from a cron job.

I used full-path in the command area like,

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/kam/public_html/filename.php
```

Comment: And what's the entry on crontab?

Comment: it retrieve data from a site and store to database [for vistor count]

Comment: I don't want to know what the script does, i want to know the cron entry, do a `crontab -l` and post the cron entry

Comment: don't know, i setup cron job in cpanel and i doesn't set anything like that..

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cURL installed, this should work:

Replace:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/kamalam4/public_html/filename.php
```

With: (replace www.your-domain.com with your own site domain/URL)

```
curl --silent --compressed http://www.your-domain.com/filename.php
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to command line and do "crontab -e" . Write the  cronjob entry

example :- to set a 1 min cron : 
*/1 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php /home/kamalam4/public_html/filename.php